# Undefined Notation for Markov Chains In Durrett's Probability

Tags: markov-chains

Let $(S,\mathcal{S})$ be a measurable space (thought of as the state space of a Markov chain). In Durrett's probability, he defines a transition probability to be a function $p:(S,\mathcal{S}) \to \mathbb{R}$ such that

1. For fixed $x \in S$, $p(x,\cdot)$ is a probability measure on $(S,\mathcal{S})$.
2. For fixed $A \in \mathcal{S}$, $p(\cdot, A)$ is a measurable function.

Then he goes on to say that $X_n$ is called a Markov chain (wrt $\mathcal{F}_n$) with transition probability $p$ if $P(X_{n+1} \in B | \mathcal{F}_n) = p(X_n,B)$. But what does $p(X_n,B)$ mean? $X_n$ is a function $X_n: \Omega \to S$, not an element of $S$. Do we interpret $X_n$ as having a fixed value $X_n=s$ and then interpret $p(X_n,B)$ as being $p(s,B)$?

Another confusing bit of notation: he goes on to define the canonical sequence space $(S^\mathbb{N}, \mathcal{S}^\mathbb{N})$ and a probability measure $P_\mu$ on it via the Kolmogorov extension theorem. He says that $P_\mu(A) = \int P_x(A) d\mu(x)$, but he never defines what $P_x$ is.

Comment: I think you are meant to read previous chapters before reading that.  In particular, he is using the notation in his chapter on martingales and regular conditional probabilities without restating them.

Comment: @user10354138 I did read the previous chapter on Martingales. Neither of these notations was defined there. My background on probability theory came from a course where we used Rosenthal, so I unfortunately didn't read the first three chapters of Durrett, but after a couple of hours of skimming them I don't see anywhere he defined this notations in the first three chapters either.

Comment: Did you figure it out by any chance? I'm also struggling to understand some notations despite having gone through the first 4 chapters...

Comment: @MoneyBall Sorry for the late reply - unfortunately I haven't figured out how to interpret $p(X_n,B)$ but I did figure out that $P_x(A)$ denotes "probability of $A$ given that the Markov chain starts at $x$", and $P_\mu(A)$ denotes "probability of $A$ given that the Markov chain has initial distribution $\mu$".